# Config entity form fails to load entity

Tags: 8, forms, entities

I have a custom config entity modelled closely on the [example documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/configuration-api/creating-a-configuration-entity-type-in-drupal-8) and [example module](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/examples.module/group/examples/8.x-1.x).  The example module works fine on my site, my code does not, and I can't see the difference.

**What works**

- Show an empty list of config entities with an add button.
- Add a config entity and check it exists via "drush cget".

**What fails**

1. In my edit settings form (extends EntityForm), $this->entity has null/default values exactly as if I were adding a new entry.  It does not load the actual entity. It does not perform validation (if I pass a URL /admin/config/content/rrssb/BADPARAM that doesn't map to an existing entity I still see a page, whereas if I do the same test with the example code, I get a 403 error).
2. In my listing page (extends ConfigEntityListBuilder), if an entity exists I get an error - for some reason the list builder fails to pass the id (machine name) from the entity when building the route.

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MissingMandatoryParametersException:
>   Some mandatory parameters are missing ("button_set") to generate a URL for
>   route "entity.rrssb_button_set.edit_form". in
>   Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->doGenerate() (line 180 of
>   core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/UrlGenerator.php).

**Details**

```
/**
 * Defines the RRSSB button set entity.
 *
 * @ConfigEntityType(
 *   id = "rrssb_button_set",
 *   label = @Translation("RRSSB Button Set"),
 *   handlers = {
 *     "list_builder" = "Drupal\rrssb\RRSSBListBuilder",
 *     "form" = {
 *       "add" = "Drupal\rrssb\Form\RRSSBSettingsForm",
 *       "edit" = "Drupal\rrssb\Form\RRSSBSettingsForm",
 *       "delete" = "Drupal\rrssb\Form\RRSSBDeleteForm",
 *     }
 *   },
 *   config_prefix = "button_set",
 *   admin_permission = "administer rrssb",
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "id",
 *     "label" = "label"
 *   },
 *   links = {
 *     "edit-form" = "/admin/config/content/rrssb/{button_set}",
 *     "delete-form" = "/admin/config/content/rrssb/{button_set}/delete",
 *     "collection" = "/admin/config/content/rrssb"
 *   }
 * )
 */
```

rrssb.routing.yml

```
entity.rrssb_button_set.collection:
  path: '/admin/config/content/rrssb'
  defaults:
    _entity_list: 'rrssb_button_set'
    _title: 'Ridiculously Responsive Social Sharing Buttons'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer rrssb'

entity.rrssb_button_set.add_form:
  path: '/admin/config/content/rrssb/add'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: 'rrssb_button_set.add'
    _title: 'Add RRSSB Button Set'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer rrssb'

entity.rrssb_button_set.edit_form:
  path: '/admin/config/content/rrssb/{button_set}'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: 'rrssb_button_set.edit'
    _title: 'Edit RRSSB Button Set'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer rrssb'

entity.rrssb_button_set.delete_form:
  path: '/admin/config/content/rrssb/{button_set}/delete'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: 'rrssb_button_set.delete'
    _title: 'Delete RRSSB Button Set'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer rrssb'
```

**Help requested**

Please can an expert suggest what I'm likely to be missing, or at least help me understand where to look?

In particular, what mechanism (Drupal class/code file) loads the config entry or generates a 403 if it is not found?

The relevant code in my own module spans several files, so I've not pasted it all here, but could upload specific snippets if asked.

Comment: We can't help without seeing at least your entity type annotation and routes if you defined them yourself.

Comment: @Berdir thanks for explaining what information I need to supply - hopefully that's now done

Comment: Shouldn't the URL param be `rrssb_button_set` and not `button_set`?

Comment: Or the reverse... Basically the id key doesn't match the parameter in the routing file.

Comment: @Kevin you are exactly right, many thanks.  I had failed to realise that the URL param must match the entity name.  If you would like to create an answer I will accept it, or I can write up the answer myself if you prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the id key isn’t matching the router parameter defined in the routing file. It should be either `button_set` or `rrssb_button_set`, depending on which one is right. Get that fixed and clear the cache and it should work.